# Mongo JSON document -> JSON -> BSON

Tags: json, mongodb, node.js, bson

I am working with Node.js to build a web socket server that uses mongodb.

I am using node-mongodb-native as the library to access mongo db.

When I call console.log(sys.inspect(item)) on an object from the db I get something that looks like this:

```
{ _id: { id: 'L?#&\u008e\u00ad\u000e\u008f\u0014\u0005\u0000\u0000' }
, y: 3
, favorite_color: 'orange'
, x: 14766
}
```

so I am guessing the id is the BSON object id that mongo uses.

I need to send this object to the client web browser using JSON, have them do some stuff to it, and then send it back to the server.

When I JSON.stringify(item), I get something that looks like this:

```
{"_id":"4c3f23268ead0e8f14050000","y":3,"favorite_color":"orange","x":14766}
```

So the id has been turned into some hex encoded string. If I send it to the client, and the client sends it back, I now need to update it in the db. I run  JSON.parse(item) to get it to be a normal object, but it still looks like this:

```
{ _id: '4c3f23268ead0e8f14050000'
, y: 3
, favorite_color: 'orange'
, x: 14766
}
```

and that _id can't be used to look up in mongodb.

How can I convert it back to a format that will be able to be used for lookups on mongo?

--update--

Interestingly I can use `findOne({_id:item._id}, collection)` to get the document, but if I do this:

`findOne({_id:{id : item._id.id}}, collection)`

I don't receive a result. I guess there is something special about the mongo _id object.

Both  `{_id:item._id}` and  `{_id:{id : item._id.id}}`
when dumped out look like this:

```
{ _id: { id: 'L?#&\u008e\u00ad\u000e\u008f\u0014\u0005\u0000\u0000' } }
```

--Another update RESOLVED---

There was some object id manipulation in an integration test file.

objectId = new mongo.ObjectID.createFromHexString('47cc67093475061e3d95369d');
will give the _id that I am looking for.

objectId.toHexString() 
will return the hex string that looks like '47cc67093475061e3d95369d'

Comment: So, your problem is solved I guess?

Comment: Nope, the real problem is I need some form of the mongo id I can send to the client browser (preferably in json) that the client can then send back which can be used to look up the object in mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `sys.inspect` interprets an [ObjectId](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs) as an object containing an `id` property. That's what you're seeing in the dump.

MongoDB treats the ObjectId as a 12-byte binary value, not as an object. So MongoDB doesn't know about any `id` property. That's why the following query yields no result:

```
findOne({_id: {id: item._id.id}}, collection)
```

The following does work, as it just treats both values as binary values:

```
findOne({_id: item._id}, collection)
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot more sense now. Is there any way to convert that object to a string or a more portable data type, and then convert it back? I need something to send to the client browser that can be sent back to identify the object.

Comment: You should send the `4c3f23268ead0e8f14050000` format to the client, as this seems to be the standard textual representation of an ObjectId. In the Mongo shell the [toString()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html#toString%28%29) method returns such a string. I expect this to be implemented in node-mongodb-native/node.js as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Something similar was available as part of the library.

Comment: you can also do JSON.stringify() on a document containing an objectid instance and it will call the toJson method on the object returning the hex representation of the objectID.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was stuck with the same error while working with python client. But I will clarify the accomplishment result for both languages.

Firstly the `_id` MongoDB returns is the BSON object. Meaning bin­ary-en­coded seri­al­iz­a­tionfor of JSON, more in this link: [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification)

Let's say you want to insert data with the following fields:

```
params = {
   "y":3,
   "favorite_color":"orange",
   "x":14766
}
```

```
client.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  var dbo = db.db("test_database");
dbo.collection("my_collection").insertOne(params, function(err, res) {
 if (err) throw err;
   console.log("inserted document",JSON.stringify(res));
    db.close();
   });
});
```

it return object result, for instance `"_id":"5e95abf57b59b448bb22dedf"`

Defining ObjectId, you can easily use findOne, updateOne methods.

```
const {ObjectId} = require('mongodb');
client.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  var dbo = db.db("test_database");
 var myquery = { "_id": ObjectId("5e95abf57b59b448bb22dedf") } ;

    dbo.collection("my_collection").findOne(myquery, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
   });

});
```

update:

```
client.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  var dbo = db.db("test_database");
   var myquery = { "_id": ObjectId("5e95abf57b59b448bb22dedf") } ;
    var newvalues = { $set: {favorite_color: "red", y: "14760" } };
    dbo.collection("my_collection").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 document updated");
      db.close();
    });
});
```

For python:

let's take this result as an example: `{'_id':ObjectId('5e95a18dcae4a4a005e14bd8')}`

```
from bson.json_util import loads as bson_loads, dumps as bson_dumps 
import json


#you should dump it then load it 
result = document = json.loads(bson_dumps(document))
{ "$set": {"status": False}}

#update:
db["my_collection"].update_one({ "_id": result},new_value)  

#find_one:
db["my_collection"].find_one({ "_id": resultjs})
```

For more to work with python MongoDB client(motor) I have created [Gist](https://gist.github.com/sabuhish/bef11d68ffb23e632e11e27227c47cfb)